# Beamer: show symbols (alpha and beta) in normal text and frame title, and increase their size

Tags: beamer, math-mode, symbols, titles, fontsize

As I specify in the title, I want to be able to include symbols like alpha and beta in my slides, in normal text format in both the body of the slide and the frame title.

Besides, I want these symbols bigger than the rest of the text...

I am not sure which packages I load in my real presentation, cause there I can see the alpha and beta symbols but I cannot alter their size. With the following MWE I cannot even see alpha and beta...

How can I accomplish this?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\huge{\alpha} and \huge{\beta} diversities}
    I want to study \huge{\alpha} and \huge{\beta} diversities, and I want \alpha\ and \beta\ to be bigger...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this:
[image: fig]

Comment: Have a look at `textgreek` and its command sequences. They should also work with beamer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax of use `\huge` and Greek letters is wrong. Try this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{{\huge $\alpha$} and {\huge $\beta$} diversities}
    I want to study {\huge $\alpha$} and {\huge $\beta$} diversities, and I want $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be bigger...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So they can only be used in math mode?

Comment: {\huge \alpha} does not seem to affect the size...

Comment: as `\alpha`, `\beta`, ... yes, should be in math mode: `$\alpha$`, etc. for text mode see *user124577* answer.  so `{\huge \alpha}` is wrong, correct is `{\huge$\alpha$}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to switch to the unicode characters and Xe/LuaLaTeX, then I recommend using `textgreek` and its `\textalpha` and so on.

[image: greek]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\huge{\textalpha} and \huge{\textbeta} diversities}
    I want to study \huge{\textalpha} and \huge{\textbeta} diversities, and I want \textalpha\ and \textbeta\ to be bigger...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get "Package textgreek Error: Cannot find the file lgrenc.def. ...GR. Maybe it comes with the babel package.}}"

Comment: `\huge` is not an environment but command which switch all after it into `huge` size. correct use is `{\hude <whatever>}`.

Comment: @DaniCee Do you use `babel`? And if yes, which language do you include?